# How to display UTF-8 characters correctly?

Tags: xml, android-studio, utf-8

I know that you start the file with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` but how to I actually go about displaying the UTF-8 character? I am specifically trying to use the treble clef, which has a UTF-8 code of `&#119070`.

I figured out how to properly implement the UTF-8 characters but now they do not display correctly. I made a string and declared it as `<string name="trc">&#119070;</string>` but the treble clef does not display. I put that string into a textview in Android Studio by using `android:text="@string/trc"`. It should print a treble clef but instead it prints this Hangul character:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "drawable"? The XML file just specifies the characters... how they're *used* is up to the application using them...

Comment: Sorry. I clarified my question. I'm trying to figure out how to correctly declare a UTF-8 character.

Comment: Did you try `&#119070;` (or `&#x1D11E;` if you want to write it in hexadecimal)? The font which you use to *display* it will need to have that code point defined appropriately.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to display it. I'll edit the question

Comment: There's a big step inbetween XML → ??? → character on screen. What exactly are you doing, what exactly are you expecting, what exactly is happening or not happening, what exactly is your screenshot showing that should probably be different?

Comment: @deceze I made the string above and then put it into a textview in Android Studio by using `android:text="@string/trc"` It should print a treble clef but instead it prints what is in the screenshot above.